# VB.NET image sharing violation

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net code that has an outside script (written in R) that creates an image and passes it to the vb.net code to display in a picturebox. This works fine when only one instance is in use.

When this image is displayed it appears to be locked in use. Attempting to edit the image while it is being shown through the script gives a a failed error. Trying to edit it in paint gives a more descriptive error of "A sharing violation has occurred".

The software may be run in multiple instances at once through several different computers connected in a network. Disposing the image means it cannot be displayed on the screen (gives the red cross image instead) and I have tried loading the image into the picturebox as a clone of the original and then disposing the original - this gives the same error as in the original problem:

```
Dim someImage as bitmap = new bitmap(fileName)
pictureBox.image = someImage.clone()
someImage.dispose()
```

Is there a way to have an image left on screen but free its access so that it can be edited by other software?

(I do not need the image to update automatically if it is changed elsewhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone() is not good enough, you need to make a deep copy of the bitmap.  In other words, not just copy the image properties but *also* copy the pixel data.  Simply done by using the Bitmap(Image) constructor:

```
    Using img = Image.FromFile(filename)
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(img)
    End Using         '' File no longer locked here
```

I added the Dispose() call, usually required.